# Cannot reset the center of an object with "Origin to Geometry"

Tags: origin

I would like to reset the center reference of the parent object model, but no matter what buttons I clicked, the location reference point is still not at the center. Can anyone please give me some advice? Thanks!

In the attached image (in the link) that shows the layers, I tried to reset the origin from the child object all the way to their parent. However, when I revised Base, any child under Base was reset but Base itself cannot be changed. The model screenshot is also attached.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NtficCjk-Mu0G1cFLHaVwCUZye6IDqTO?usp=drive_link

Comment: Hello your link asks for an authorization

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NtficCjk-Mu0G1cFLHaVwCUZye6IDqTO?usp=sharing

So sorry just updated!

Comment: could you please share the file itself? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Yep! Just uploaded the file to the drive! Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please reformulate what you are trying to do? What is the "center reference" or the "location reference point", or "revise" or "reset" for example? The object called Base is an empty for example, you can't change its origin position

Comment: Yep! The ultimate goal is to align the robot arm's location with the model so that the arm and the center of the model share the same y value wrt to the global frame. My initial attempt was to set their y location manually, but I realize that the reference center, i.e. the x, y, z location in transform of the model is not at the center. Hence, I cannot adjust the position by matching the y value directly. This is the reason why I want to reset the center of the model. I hope this makes more sense! Thanks!